# use slideDown after image loads

Tags: jquery

i use [gpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/) library for charts drawing. i need to dinamicaly create graphs, so i use jquery for it.

Look at this script please

```
$("#graph").click(function(u)
{
  var f = 502; //just for example
  $("#graph_content").html('<img src="mygraph.php?value1='+f+'" />');
  $("#graph_content").slideDown(600);
  u.stopPropagation();
});
```

in `mygraph.php` i generate the image of graphic, depend on `value1`.

but i need to `slideDown()` the div with image after it loads. in my case while it loads an image, it allready slides down a `div`, so i lose effect i wanted. 
i can't imagine how can i use `load` method here?

maybe you will help me:)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#graph").click(function(u) {
  var f = 502;
  $("#graph_content").html('<img src="mygraph.php?value1='+f+'" id="image" />');
  $("#image").load(function(){
    $("#graph_content").slideDown(600);
  }); 
  u.stopPropagation();
});​
```

or this should also work:

```
$("#graph").click(function(u) {
  var f = 502;
  $('<img src="mygraph.php?value1='+f+'" />')
     .load(function(){
        $("#graph_content").slideDown(600);
     })
     .appendTo("#graph_content");

  u.stopPropagation();
});​
```

If the #graph_content element is empty.

Comment: i like your solutionS. Thanks much;)